# counting appearence of difference combinations coming from same column?

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery

I want to count how many person did participate in 2 course combinations

Let's say I have a table1:

```
Name    course
-----------------
Mary    Biology
Mary    Chemistry
Mary    Music
Kim     Music
Kim     Chemistry
Kim     Mathematics
Ida     Mathematics
Ida     Biology
Ida     Music
```

results should be like this

```
Biology   Chemistry   1
Biology   music       2
Chemistry music       2
Mathematics music     2
```

This is what I got, but isn't working.

```
select * From (
select t1.course, t2.course, count (*) AS total from 
(select
t1.name t1.course, t2.course
from data t1
JOIN data t2 ON t1.name=t2.name
where t1.course<>t2.course)
group by t1.name,t1.course,t2.course)
order by total desc;
```

Comment: can you tag the dbms being used? like sql server, oracle, mysql, postgresql..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for BigQuery Legacy SQL or BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
SELECT 
  a.course as course_a, 
  b.course as course_b, 
  COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM rekry_data a 
JOIN rekry_data b 
ON a.Name=b.Name
WHERE a.course < b.course
GROUP BY a.course, b.course
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.course, b.course, COUNT(*)
FROM mytable a JOIN mytable b ON a.Name=b.Name AND a.Course <> b.Course 
GROUP BY a.course, b.course
```